# php/codeigniter firestore update giving error InvalidArgumentException Input missing required one or more required keys

Tags: php, firebase, codeigniter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect admin panel on php-codeigniter with firestore/firebase . Insertion,Fetch and Set functions are working fine but when I try to update ( update a single key ) it gives InvalidArgumentException . I am following the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data) . I am new to firestore. Suggestions are appreciated.

Here's my code

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Kreait\Firebase\Factory;

class Panelmodel extends CI_Model
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $factory = (new Factory)->withServiceAccount(FCPATH . "/settings/firebase.json")
            ->createFirestore();
        $this->db = $factory->database();
    }


function update($id)
    {
        $document = $this->db->collection('Users')
            ->document($id);

        $document->update([['status' => false]]);
    }


}
```

Error Output

```
<h4>An uncaught Exception was encountered</h4>

<p>Type: InvalidArgumentException</p>
<p>Message: Input missing required one or more required keys. Required keys are path, value</p>
<p>Filename: /var/www/doer/vendor/google/cloud-core/src/ValidateTrait.php</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my understanding of provided documentation `update` syntax should be like this:

```
$document->update([
       ['path' => 'status' , 'value' => false]
]);
```

[Here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.19.2/firestore/documentreference?method=update) is API documentation. The syntax from the code should work with `set` ([reference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/cloud-firestore/v1.19.2/firestore/documentreference?method=set)).